# Expectation of maximum draw down in the Brownian motion case

Tags: brownian-motion, drawdown, maximum-drawdown

Let 
$$
X_t = \mu t + \sigma B_t
$$
be a linear Brownian motion with drift. 
Let 
$$
S_t = \max(X_u, u \le t)
$$
denote the process of the running max, then the draw down is given by
$$
DD_t = S_t - X_t,
$$
and the maximum draw down over a period  $[0,T]$ is $$max_{u \in [0,T]} DD_u.$$
What can we say about $$E[ max_{u \in [0,T]} DD_u ] ?$$ 
How can we calculate the expected maximum draw down? Are there analytical formulas, approximations, available (R) packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as I mentioned [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/6997/comparison-of-brownian-motion-expected-drawdown-and-simulated-results?rq=1), [this](http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~amir/drawdown-jrnl.pdf) paper provides some theoretical insight (and a way to approximate the true value).

The authors end up with an approximative series for the density. It is implemented in the function maxdd of the R-package **fBasics**. There are convenient functions *dmaxdd*, *pmaxdd* and *rmaxdd*. Calculating the Expected Drawdown should be easy. (to be honest, I found the paper as a reference provided on the help page of the functions mentioned above)

The function you are asking for would be **maxddStats**:

```
require(fBasics)
maxddStats(mu,sigma,t)
```

Comment: looking at maxddStats it looks as if they use simple MC ...

Comment: @Richard Maybe it appears to be a MC simulation because of the default value for $t$, which is $1000$, but to me the code .maxddStats looks like a numerical quadrature with precomputed values which are hard-coded into the function. I didn't look into it in more detail though.