# Geometric Brownian Motion: Drawdown as a function of time

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Suppose I have a strategy (model it as the usual geometric Brownian motion with a drift). Question is, how does max drawdown grow as a function of duration?

Comment: This should do: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053294/density-of-first-hitting-time-of-brownian-motion-with-drift

Comment: @Lipton Do tell.

Comment: After a second thought, realised that i was thinking of min rather than max drawdown, and thought that if we know the distribution of the min for a Brownian motion with drift, then we can figure out the distribution of the asked min. But in any case, this question seems to have answered it: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17589/expectation-of-maximum-draw-down-in-the-brownian-motion-case