# What is the Probability Distribution of Max-Drawdown?

Tags: time-series, returns, probability, normal-distribution, maximum-drawdown

**How to obtain the probability distribution of Maximum Drawdown, starting from the probability distribution of Daily Returns? Here the details:**

Suppose I have a time serie of **N=1000 daily returns**.

Each daily return is normally distributed, like **[μ=1\$,σ=10\$]**

Suppose I run **100 simulations** of that time series. At every simulation I create a new realisation of the time series, by I pulling 1000 random values from that normal distribution **[μ=1\$,σ=10\$]**.

At every simulation I calculate the **Maximum Drawdown** (MDD).

Obviously, I get a different MDD every time, because each of the 100 realisations of the time series is different, although they all originate from the same normal distribution.

I want to generalise these results and understand how MDD varies as a function on μ, σ, N days. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome! And nice markup. You know that there is the option of latex too? $N(\mu=1, \sigma=10)$?

Comment: oook next time latex 

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer you're looking for is very similar to this question
[Expectation of maximum draw down in the Brownian motion case](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17589/expectation-of-maximum-draw-down-in-the-brownian-motion-case).

just like your assumption that return is normally distributed with mu and sig, say price/portfolio value follows Brownian motion with same property, and if you're using log return, I found [this article](http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~amir/mdd-risk.pdf) that provides an analytical formula for the mean of distribution of max drawdown.